# Displaying data from Firebase on load of Ionic app

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm a beginner in Ionic and Firebase. To learn using ionic+firebase, I'm writing a RandomQuote app to fetch a random entry from Firebase. A reload() method is called when I click a reload button, and the random quote is displayed as expected.

However, I also want the quote to display when the app is loaded, i.e., before I click the reload button. I call the reload() method in the constructor but it doesn't work. I have tried to search for answers on the web but cannot find anything that I could understand. Not sure if I'm searching the wrong keywords or in the wrong domains.

The following is the reload() method that I put in my FirebaseProvider class and called from my home.ts:

```
reload(){
    this.afd.list('/quoteList/').valueChanges().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.oneQuote = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
      }
    )
    return this.oneQuote;
}
```

Can anyone give me some hints? Or any pointer to useful books / materials for beginners will also be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. This means that by the time your `return` statement runs `this.oneQuote` doesn't have a value yet.

This is easiest to say by placing a few log statements around your code:

```
console.log("Before subscribing");
this.afd.list('/quoteList/').valueChanges().subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log("Got data");
  }
)
console.log("After subscribing");
```

When you run this code, the output is:

> Before subscribing
>
> After subscribing
>
> Got data

This is probably not what you expected. But it completely explains why your `return` statement doesn't return the data: that data hasn't been loaded yet.

So you need to make sure your code that needs the data runs after the data has been loaded. There are two common ways to do this:

1. By moving the code into the callback
2. By returning a promise/subscription/observable

Moving the code into the callback is easiest: when the `console.log("Got data")` statement runs in the code above, the data is guaranteed to be available. So if you move the code that requires the data into that place, it can use the data without problems.

Returning a promise/subscription/observable is a slightly trickier to understand, but nicer way to doing the same. Now instead of moving the code-that-needs-data into the callback, you'll return "something" out of the callback that exposes the data when it is available. In the case of AngularFire the easiest way to do that is to return the actual observable itself:

```
return this.afd.list('/quoteList/').valueChanges();
```

Now the code that needs the quotes can just subscribe to the return value and update the UI:

```
reload().subscribe(data => {
  this.oneQuote = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
}
```

A final note: having a `reload()` method sounds like an antipattern. The subscription will already be called whenever the data in the quoteList changes. There is no need to call `reload()` for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. I can confirm that it solves my problem. It also clarifies my concept a lot.

May I ask further why you say that the second approach is a nicer way to do it?

Comment: It allows you to separate the code-that-requires-the-data more consistently from the code-that-reads-the-data. But it's subjective. I still default to writing callbacks, because thats what I've done for the longest time.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.